# Index of list of list and return the position of a element in list of list

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm currently trying to create a simple connect 4 game where the board is defined as follow

```
> testboard :: [[Char]]
> testboard = [['B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
>         ['B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
>         ['B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
>         ['B','B','B','X','X','B','B'],
>         ['B','B','O','O','X','B','B'],
>         ['B','O','O','X','X','X','B']]
```

I want to create a function that returns the highest row the column has not yet been filled By X or O
eg if I put column 4 it should return the highest row that its not filled in column 4 is 3 (from top down)

here is my attempt

```
 getlist :: [[Char]] -> Char -> Int -> [[Char]]
 getlist list char col =  [[x | x <- z , x == char] | z <- list]
```

but this would only return the rows that have that specific value disregarding the column positions so I tried this

```
getlist list char col =  [[x | (i,x) <- zip [0..] list , i == col] | z <- list]
```

and I cant seem to get it to work please help

Comment: You could extract the column first, as in `[ z!!col | z<-list ]`. Then you can count how many blanks there are at the beginning. Also, the type looks wrong: do you really want to return `... -> [[Char]]`? Don't you need an integer result?

Comment: @chi I tried doing int but for some reason on vs code it tells me It cant match type Char to [Char] for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As chi notes in comments, you can extract the column you want with `!!`.

```
Prelude> map (!! 3) testboard
"BBBXOX"
```

Now, if we use `takeWhile (== 'B')` we can get the leading blanks.

```
Prelude> takeWhile (== 'B') $ map (!! 3) testboard
"BBB"
```

Using this, writing a `blankDepth` function is trivial, and that will doubtless help you on your way to your solution.

```
blankDepth :: Int -> [[Char]] -> Int
blankDepth col = length . takeWhile (== 'B') . map (!! col)
```

```
Prelude> blankDepth 3 testboard
3
Prelude> blankDepth 5 testboard
5
Prelude> blankDepth 1 testboard
5
Prelude> blankDepth 6 testboard
6
```